# IntelliJ 2017 slow compile of sample play sbt app

Tags: java, sbt, playback

takes over 5 min to compile the play-java-starter-example from play's own site

- i've tried upping the vm mem options
- i've tried updateOptions :=
  updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
- i've tried setting sbt
  compiler to various options in IJ

Comment: sbt means it's compiling Scala, which is notoriously slow at compiling. There isn't really anything you can do about it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Play Java Starter Example from https://example.lightbend.com/v1/download/play-java-starter-example and compiled it.

There is a one time cost of fetching SBT and the project dependencies (including the Scala library) which may run into a few minutes depending on your Ivy cache and connection. I already had most of the libraries in my cache so it definitely took less than 5 minutes.

After that, compilation will be relatively fast. The following command takes about 14 seconds on my machine.

```
time sbt ";clean;compile"
```

Note that by keeping the SBT shell open you will amortize the SBT startup cost, which can be around 10s.

```
sbt
> clean
> compile
```

This way the code gets compiled in about 7 seconds on my machine.